# Is there an Excel Keyboard Shortcut for freezing the top row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there an Excel Keyboard Shortcut for freezing the top row?

I'm currently using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in shortcut for this. You can try the following options, though:

1. Press **Alt** + **W**, then **F**, then **R**. This is the equivalent of selecting it with the mouse from the View tab.

   - optional: bind this sequence to a shortcut using an Excel macro or, say, an AutoHotkey script.
2. Add that command to the Quick Access toolbar at the top of the window.

Which one works best for you depends on how much time you want to spend on it, and whether you're faster with the keyboard or with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

As indrek mentioned, create a macro and assign the macro a shortcut. (could be better ways to write this but it worked for me in excel 2007).

IF you want the shortcut available to any file you open, you will need to create it in a 'Personal Macro Workbook' without going into excruciating detail on this process, one way to auto create this is by recording a new macro, and selecting 'Personal Macro Workbook' instead of storing it in 'This Workbook' from the record macro window.

```
Sub freezetoprow()
Range("a1").Activate
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 2010 but in 2007 it's under view tab then half way across it's freeze cells.  I do know that Microsoft had an interactive help solution where you click where it was on the previous version you had and it shows on the new version... now IF they have that between 2007 to 2010 I am not sure.  Of course you can always help... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using excel 2013

Go to: 
'File'
    'Options'
         'Quick Access Toolbar'
Scroll down to 'Freeze Panes' and double click or select it and click 'Add'

I am not sure if this option is available in later versions

Comment: How is this related to a "keyboard shortcut"? The question asks about a Keyboard Shortcut and the feature.